# Using VUE.js to load content

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object

I am trying to render 2 messages using vue.js but it wont seem to load on FE?

```
<template v-for="item in items">
    <span>{{ afterpayMessage }}: {{ item.price }} with AfterPay</span>
</template>

<script>
  var afterpay = new Vue({
  el: '#afterpay',
  data: {
    afterpayMessage: 'Or 4 payments of',
    items: [
      { price: {{ product.price | money_with_currency | json }} },
    ]
  }
})
</script>
```

I haven tried to use the following code, which was kindly suggested to include a return function, but all that renders is the 'with afterpay' text and not the templates.

```
<div id="afterpay" v-for="item in items">
    {{ afterpayMessage }}: {{ item.price }} with AfterPay
</div>

<script>
  var afterpay = new Vue({
  el: '#afterpay',
    data: function () {
      return {
        afterpayMessage: 'Or 4 payments of',
        items: [
          { price: {{ product.price | money_with_currency | json }} },
         ]
      }
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this data format

data: function () {
  return {
    afterpayMessage: 'Or 4 payments of',
    items: [
      { price: {{ product.price | money_with_currency | json }} },
    ]
  }
}